# nginx slow on every second request

Tags: node.js, nginx

I'm currently creating an api for my website, using nodejs and nginx, I've setup reversed proxies for each nodejs app i'll have running (api, mainsite, other stuff..).

However, when i try my api, it will use a very long time on every second request, sometimes time out..

NGINX.CONF

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user              nginx;
worker_processes  24;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  19000;
    multi_accept    on;
}


http {
    include     /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type    application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    #SSL performance tuning
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!eNULL:!NULL:!DH:!EDH:!AESGCM;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
    ssl_session_cache       shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout     10m;

    ssl_stapling        on;
    ssl_stapling_verify     on;
    resolver            8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
    resolver_timeout        10s;
    add_header          Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay             on;
    keepalive_timeout       10;

    gzip            on;
    gzip_disable        "msie6";
    gzip_min_length     1000;
    gzip_proxied        expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types          text/plain application/xml application/javascript text/css application/x-javascript;  

    #for mulyiple domains, www.codewolf.red, codewolf.red
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

    # Load config files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory
    # The default server is in conf.d/default.conf
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

}
```

ERROR.LOG

```
2014/10/27 14:26:46 [error] 6968#8992: *15 WSARecv() failed (10054: FormatMessage() error:(317)) while reading response header from upstream, client: ::1, server: localhost, request: "GET /api/ffd/users HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/ffd/users", host: "localhost"

2014/10/27 14:27:46 [error] 6968#8992: *15 upstream timed out (10060: FormatMessage() error:(317)) while connecting to upstream, client: ::1, server: localhost, request: "GET /api/ffd/users HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[::1]:3000/ffd/users", host: "localhost"

2014/10/27 14:39:31 [error] 6968#8992: *20 upstream timed out (10060: FormatMessage() error:(317)) while connecting to upstream, client: ::1, server: localhost, request: "GET /api/ffd/users HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[::1]:3000/ffd/users", host: "localhost"
2014/10/27 14:40:09 [notice] 5300#1352: signal process started
```

Any idea whats wrong? 
It's been like this for a while, and its killing me :(

Please help, it's ruining my time for developing apps :/

Comment: Have you tried bypassing NGinx and connecting directly to your app? It looks like Nginx is having trouble connecting to upstream which I guess is your app.

Comment: Yes, I have. I tried something new by setting an upstream variable and using that instead of http://localhost:2345/. And it all works now! :)

I'll write a proper answer where i'll explain how i fixed it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix this by using an upstream statement.

eg. :

```
upstream nodejs_server {
    server 192.168.0.67:8080;   #ip to nodejs server
}

#server config
server {
    location /nodejsServer/ {    #http://localhost/nodejsServer/
        proxy_pass http://nodejs_server;
    }
}
```

reference: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html

Comment: This issue may be caused by the use of the loopback interface(localhost) as a binding target for the target server and nginx respectively, the use of the real local address resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 6):

Adding this because this is what worked for me

https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?15,239760,239760 Seems to indicate that you can proxy_pass to 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost and the request goes through fine

> macbresch
>
> One year old but I wanted to point out that there is a work around for that issue. Like Cruz Fernandez wrote you can set 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost on the proxy_pass directive. This prevents the 60s delay on every second request. I'm using Windows 8.1 and nginx 1.9.5.
>
> Cruz Fernandez Wrote:
>
> you can use 127.0.0.1 (instead of localhost on the proxy_pass directive)

```
location /nodejsServer/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
}
```